# order by with entity frameworks

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, silverlight

I need to show the result of this query with a silverlight treeview using entity frameworks :

```
Select * from table1 order by ParentID,sortnum
```

my table's fields are:ID,Name,ParentID,sortnum

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I need to do this query Select * from table1 order by ParentID,sortnum

Answer (score 0):

Add the Entity Framework to the Project. On the code behind, execute the LINQ query.

Step 1: Create Object for the Entity Model.

Step 2: Execute the LINQ Query as follows.

```
Entity e = new Entity();
var tab = (from x in e.table1 order by x.ParentID descending select x).ToList<>();
```

add the data from **tab** to the treeview.

Comment: I need order by ParentID,sortnum. not only ParentID

Comment: you can add the next order by parameter next to it like below..


var tab = (from x in e.table1 order by x.ParentID descending, x.sortnum ascending select x).ToList<>();

Comment: thank you, I am new to this stuff that is why I have some difficulties